# What does the !! mean in this Ruby function?

Tags: ruby

What does the !! mean in this Ruby function?

```
def is_i?
   !!(self =~ /^[-+]?[0-9]+$/)
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It makes sure the response is a boolean. So `nil` or `false` wil become `false`, any other value becomes `true`